# Is JSON better than passing normal Java objects in the response?

Tags: java, json, httpresponse

I'm sure one of you experts can either answer this or point me to an explanation.

Lets say I have a list of 300 cars from which I want the user to choose.
Each of these Java objects has 10 properties (e.g. model, manufacturer, color, age...).

The question is, is it more efficient to pass all 300 in JSON format in the response, or simply pass a List and use JSTL to display them?

Since something like Simple-JSON is a wrapper for List and Map, is there really a benefit?

Or when does using JSON make sense verses passing normal Java objects?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your response content-type? If it's application/json, you return JSOn. If it's text/html, you return HTML.

Comment: You can't pass objects between processes. You have to serialize them in some fashion.

Comment: Interesting question. I would say that if your content response is JSON, then return a JSON `String`, otherwise use Java objects and set them as request attributes before forwarding to the next view. You could measure the net bandwidth to check if there's a real advantage using one approach or the other. By the way, sending 300 objects in a list in a single request should be a bad practice at all, you should at most pass 50 or 100, and use pagination to retrieve the next elements.

Comment: JSON is probably better because it would be more reusable

Comment: Java objects cannot be passed directly to a Web browser. Instead they are passed to a templating engine such as Velocity, Freemarker, or JSTL, which usually renders them to HTML using a template you have written. If you are passing back JSON, you will need to fill in the data client side using Javascript or some Javascript templating engine.

Comment: It should be pointed out that a JSON array is effectively a comma-separated-value string, one of the most compact ways to ship data uncompressed.  A JSON "object" is less compact since each value has an accompanying key.  (And I suspect when you say "normal Java object" you're maybe imagining the `toString` representation of Maps and Lists.  That's virtually identical to JSON in both size and representation, but not as well standardized.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON would be a more neutral technology than Java objects, serialized or not, and would leave you more options down the road. It's just text, so you are no longer bound to using Java. You could still use any server side templating engine, or you could send it to the browser and let JQuery or AngularJS iterate it for example.

Comment: +1 suggesting separation of concerns (back end / front end). In recent projects I treat my back end as a REST-ful API producing/consuming JSONs + it renders some static HTMLs. The rest happens in front end per AJAX requests.

Comment: Ok, so if my concern is a possible change in the front-end templating, or the possible use of other modules created in different languages, the best course of action would be to stick to JSON since it is generic format that can be read by many languages.

But if these are not concerns (which at this point they are not since this is a single application written only by me) then using regular Java would be fine.

From what I'm gathering here, the only concern is future compatibility.  As far as efficiency, there does not seem to be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in single application just stick to java.

If you are in distributed system in which modules can be written in different languages use JSON/XML

Comment: Only use XML if you're into self-abuse.